# Get Card Information from Charge object in Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have integrated stripe payment method in website . I want to get Card Information. Everything is work fine .After successful payment i successfully retrived payment id from `$charge->id` variable .So my question is that when i `print_r($charge)` it also show Card Object Something like That

```
 Stripe_Card Object ( [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_...                       
 [_values:protected] => Array ( [id] => card_1BLSPnJ6IzxnlSnmegEq6dbH 
[object] => card [address_city] => Lahire [address_country] => Pakistan
```

my stripe process

```
$customer =Stripe_Customer::create(array(
'email' => $_GET['email'],));
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(       
"amount" => $amount_cents,"currency" => "usd","source" => 
$_POST['stripeToken'],"description" => $description,      
 )              
 );
```

I try many times to get card information from `$charge` variable using `$charge->card->address_country` But not work any solution .Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ywain Thanks For Correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment source of a charge is returned in the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-source) attribute of the [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object), so you should be able to do something like this:

```
$card = $charge->source;
// Do something with $card, e.g. access the billing address' country
// with $card->address_country
```

Comment: Ywain another how do i get last digit of card from `$charge` ?

Comment: `$card` will contain a [card object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object), so you access any attribute of a card object, e.g. [`last4`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object-last4).

Comment: how can i get information from customer object , i tried  `$source=$customer->source`  , `$source->id` , it not work for me ,so i tired `$customer['id']` its work fine , but now how can i get card information from `$customer` object .Thanks